# How can I make a simple browser user-agent parser in Perl?

Tags: perl, user-agent

I needed to make a simple browser user agent parser in Perl. I have found a PHP code that does this but my knowledge is rather limited (esp. in regular expressions). So, here is the code whose Perl equivalent I want to write.

```
if ($l = ereg($pattern, $agent, $a = array()))
        {
          array_push($found, array("product" => $a[1], "version" => $a[3], "comment" => $a[6]));
          $agent = substr($agent, $l);
        }
```

The $agent is the user-agent string passed as argument, and returns an array of associative arrays $found, each one defining a product/comment in the agent string (key of the associative array are product, version, comment). The $pattern is the user-agent regular expression I am searching which I already know.

So, how would this look like in Perl?

**Edit: Seems like there is an confusion about whether I want a Perl compatible regex or an equivalent function in Perl. I am looking for an Perl function and syntax that does the same thing.**

Comment: You need to find out what's the content of `$pattern` variable

Comment: Are you converting a PHP function to Perl, or a PHP POSIX regular expression into a Perl-compatible regular expression?

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn I'm converting a PHP function to Perl. I already know what $pattern is. Just need to find the equivalent Perl syntax for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script could be written in Perl like :

```
my @found;
if ($agent =~ s/$pattern//) {
  push @found, {product => $1, version => $3, comment => $6};
}
```

In order to print the content of array @found :

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\@found);
```

Comment: thanks but what about the substr part? what is the value in $l in the case of php.

Comment: `s/$pattern//` removes the pattern (if found), that do the substr in the same instruction.

Comment: yah thanx for reminding me of that. could you tell me what the push function is doing. found is an array here but the values push are like a key and value structure in hash. so how would i print the end result from found? doing print "@found" doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [CPAN module `HTTP::BrowserDetect`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP%3a%3aBrowserDetect) to sniff out various information about the browser and the device it runs on, including but by far not limited to version, engine and vendor.

Answer (score -1):

Using [POSIX (ereg_*)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php) functions is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. If you use [PCRE (preg_*)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) functions istead, they will work in perl as well. PCRE is an abbreviation for `Perl Compatible Regular Expressions`. If you need any help with rewriting the pattern for PCRE, post the original pattern.